# Ruby replace string if next letter is found

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I want to replace a pattern in Ruby only if the next letter after the pattern is one of the given.

Example: replace "αυ" with "av" ONLY IF next letter after "αυ" is one of the followings: *α|γ|δ|λ|μ|ν|ρ|σμ|ω*

This code will not work of course, I suppose I need to use a regex more complicate to match one of the letter after the pattern.

```
string.gsub!("αυ", "av") if string =~ /α|γ|δ|λ|μ|ν|ρ|σμ|ω/
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a positive lookahead:

```
string.gsub!(/αυ(?=α|γ|δ|λ|μ|ν|ρ|σμ|ω)/, "av")
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/kuh6vpMJbh)

**Details**

- `αυ` - a `αυ` substring
- `(?=α|γ|δ|λ|μ|ν|ρ|σμ|ω)` - a positive lookahead that requires the presence of one of the alternatives inside it while excluding the alternative inside the match value, i.e. it will be left in the resulting string).

You may also "contract" the single-char alternations into a character class

```
/αυ(?=[αγδλμνρω]|σμ)/
      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [another Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/B8w6YAcNGL). `σμ` cannot be put inside a character class since it contains 2 chars.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. I was missing this: `?=` in a rexexp !